# Use 2 different MySQL databases on a single site

Tags: php, mysql, database

I would like to create 2 different websites for 2 different products, both websites will have different MySQL databases and then I would like to create 1 database common for both of them(the third one).

My question is if it is doable if does worth it (optimization and organization purposes) and if Yes what would be a best solution.

**Real Estate**  website  with (db1 + **db3**)
   **Hotel Bookings** website with (db2 + **db3**)

My intention is to create 3 MySQL databases:

**1st** database for Real Estate website with tables of homes, users, agencies, used only on Real Estate website

**2nd** database for Hotel website with database with tables of hotels, clients, hotel operators, etc.used only on Hotel Bookings website.

**3rd** GEO database (read only) with GEO data
   as countries, provinces, regions, cities, GPS coordinates of all over the world used on both websites.

The third database I would use for both websites as a "informational" database, the reason why is that only GEO database will be very huge having milions of records, so main purpose is for better organization, optimization of both future websites. GEO database will be READ ONLY with precreated already known data which will be rarely updated (I would updated them via PHPMyAdmin only) and this database should also be installed on another server.

Comment: Why have multiple DBs anyway? There is no need.

Comment: 3 databases.. I think is too much

Comment: 1 database for every website and 1 for both of them (read only GEO data), so not 3 databases, but 2 for every website from which 1 will be common for both of them

Answer (score 0):

It is actually a good idea if all databases will be on same server. It will be much clearer to have them seperated.
Question is: would you use same GEO cordinates on both sites? If GEO database will be very big, it will be better to seperate it for performance reasons (if you will use distance calculation on your websites).
I have used GEO calculation on one of my websites and it was very power consuming.

Comment: Yes, I know I can, but appending one huge only informational READ ONLY database(db3) to both db1 and db2 I hoped I will not need to create these huge COUNTRY, REGION, CITIES .... tables twice for every database (db1 and db2) , so thought I that I will resolve it by simply creating third database (db3) appending those data to both databases (db1+db2)

Comment: Sorry, i have missread your question first. I`m starting to help on this site and I`m trying to do it too fast :)

Comment: Yes exactly GEO countries, regions, cities, coordinates, will use the same data, the same as most geolocation websites use. That's why I asked, because first I wanted to design 2 databases for 2 websites with similar data, then I have realized I would use third database for the same data for both websites which will be READ ONLY so not writeable. So I wanted to know which possibilities I have and which way I should go.

Comment: So, if it will be on same server go your way. This was actually very good idea.

Comment: Thanks Radoslaw, Yes, in better case I want it on the same server, if websites significately grows and if this solution improves optimization I would also move it on another server, that's why I think about it now, if does worth it, if it helps and to know how to design those databases now (with or without GEO data which data are already very big) and which I would use separately.

Comment: And Yes distance, radius calculations were the main reasons why to separate this third database, another reason is that I already have almost 2GB of data with ZIP codes, continents, countries, regions, cities, GPS coordinates etc, I can't immagine to create those tables for 2 different websites databases and then expect great performance. If third database performance would be a issue I would use more powerful server only for it.